# When to use ApexPages.StandardController

Tags: apex, visualforce, standardcontroller

I want to know that when to use **ApexPages.StandardController** in controller.

Anyone can explain me with proper usecase.

--tia

Answer (score 1):

StandardController objects reference the pre-built Visualforce controllers provided by Salesforce. The only time it is necessary to refer to a Standard Controller object is when defining an extension for a standard controller. StandardController is the data type of the single argument in the extension class constructor.

> ApexPages.StandardController sc = new ApexPages.StandardController(sObject);

This StandardController will provide you all the information which is performed by native controller such as current Record info, native save button, cancel button etc functionality.

Answer (score 1):

`ApexPages.StandardController` is used when:

- You want to override standard buttons on a custom object detail page,
  related list, list view etc
- Use that Visualforce page as custom button or Action
- Enhance the functionality of detail page, related list etc. Something
  which can not be done natively.

  `ApexPages.StandardController` provide a way to access the record on which you want to add extended functionality. It gives all default methods of standard detail page like `Save`, `Edit` etc.